# not able to use GCP secret-manager with GCP cloud functions(nodeJS)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-secret-manager

I'm trying to access secrets stored in GCP secret manager. using following sample code and before deploy its transpiled using babel.

```
const { SecretManagerServiceClient } = require("@google-cloud/secret-manager");

const client = new SecretManagerServiceClient();
exports.hello = () => {
  //do something with client
};
```

transpiled version of the same

```
"use strict";

var _require = require("@google-cloud/secret-manager"),
    SecretManagerServiceClient = _require.SecretManagerServiceClient;

var client = new SecretManagerServiceClient();

exports.hello = function () {//do something with client
};
```

however I'm getting following error at secret manager instantiation(`const client = new SecretManagerServiceClient();`)

```
Detailed stack trace: Error: Node.js v10.0.0 is a minimum requirement. To learn about legacy version support visit: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node#supported-nodejs-versions
     at new GrpcClient (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/secret-manager/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js:63:19)
     at new SecretManagerServiceClient (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/secret-manager/build/src/v1/secret_manager_service_client.js:99:25)
     at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/index.js:6:14)
     at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
     at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

I'm able to access/modify secret using the same library when I try in my local machine. however it doesn't seem to work with CFs.

CF service account has access to secret-manager.

any help would be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Comment: The error says you need to use Node version 10 or higher. Specify the version when you deploy your Cloud Function.

Comment: @sethvargo thanks for pointing out. I fee sooo stupid, even though I noticed the error, I thought transpiling everything...  but not the library. :(

Comment: Did you solve the issue by indicating the runtime?

Comment: yes. apparently `secret-manager` expects node 10+ to run, so specifying runtime during deployment helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @sethvargo, specifying runtime during deployment solved the issue.